# EasyAdmin plus DoctrineBehavior Translatable

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2, symfony2-easyadmin

Trying to find solution how to make work EasyAdmin bundle with DoctrineBehavoir Translatable together. Can somebody help me? May be have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the DoctrineBehaviors bundle of KnpLabs with the A2lixTranslationFormBundle for creating the translations form inside easyadmin

```
- { property: 'translations', type: 'a2lix_translations' }
```

by just following the  installations steps of the bundles it gives me the basic functionnality. ( working on 2.8 symfony version )